# How do I prevent graph elements from reaching the axis of my graph in D3 and scale properly?

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, axis, element

I have currently have a quick test for a graph I'm about to create for website and I have made the most basic functionality. I have a graph, a 4 elements and an x and a y axis and a zoom functionality.

My problem lies in the fact that when I zoom on the graph, the elements are able to reach the axis and overlap it. I've pasted my source code below

```
    //Setting generic width and height values for our SVG.
    var margin = {top: 60, right: 0, bottom: 60, left: 40},
        width = 1024 - 70 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 668 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     //Other variable declarations.


    //Creating scales used to scale everything to the size of the SVG.
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1024])
        .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([1, 768])
        .range([height, 0]);

    //Creates an xAxis variable that can be used in our SVG.
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");

    //Zoom command ...
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(xScale)
        .y(yScale)
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomTargets);


    // The mark '#' indicates an ID. IF '#' isn't included argument expected is a tag such as "svg" or "p" etc..
    var SVG = d3.select("#mainSVG")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(zoom);


    //Create background. The mouse must be over an object on the graph for the zoom to work. The rectangle will cover the entire graph.
    var rect = SVG.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    //Showing the axis that we created earlier in the script for both X and Y.
    var xAxisGroup = SVG.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    var yAxisGroup = SVG.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    //This selects 4 circles (non-existent, there requires data-binding) and appends them all below enter.
    //The amount of numbers in data is the amount of circles to be appended in the enter() section. 
    var circle = SVG
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data([40,100,400,1900])
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(d)})
            .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d)})
            .attr("r",20);

    //Resets zoom when click on circle object. Zoom work now, should be changed to a button instead of click on circle though.
    SVG.selectAll("circle").on("click", function() {
        zoom.scale(1);
        zoom.translate([0,0]);
        zoomTargets();
    });

    function zoomTargets() {
       SVG.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
       SVG.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

       SVG.selectAll("circle").attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(d)}).attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d)});
    }

    function resetZoom() {
        zoom.scale(1);
        zoom.translate([0,0]);
        zoomTargets();
    }
```

I've tried using "append("g2") before creating a circle to I can make g2 smaller than the entire svg, but that doesn't seem to work. As far as I have understood, you can just append a new element inside your existing one. I'm guessing I'm wrong since it hasn't worked for me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave a small gap between the most extreme data point and the axis. In particular, you may want the range of your domain to take the margins into account:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1024])
    .range([0, width-margin.right]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1, 768])
    .range([height, margin.bottom]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, I can see why I should use the margins, but I'm still not quiet sure on how I can create a gap between my data points and my axis. Assuming I have the value for my most extreme data point. Where do I apply the gap?

Comment: You can see an the graph here btw: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/

You can use the mouse to move the objects on the graph on top of the axis at the moment. I've applied the margins to the scale as well.

Comment: Oh, you want to make this work in conjunction with zoom? Either use a clip path or [constrained zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520).

Comment: No, I'll try re-explain it :). I want to keep the type of zoom I have as I want the axis to stay in place and change values according to my zoom. When I zoom and move the elements on the graph, I want to prevent the elements from being able to get to the axis. The elements cover the axis when they are moved and then move out of the frame afterwwards. My wish is for the elements to exit the frame before reaching the axis, but I'd like to keep the way the axis changes and stays in place when zoomed in/out.

Comment: Ok, you can use a clip path for the chart area for that.